# Ordinary Differential Equation with 3 unknowns

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve the IVP system $\displaystyle{\begin{cases}x_1'=3x_1-4x_2+4x_3\\x_2'=4x_1-5x_2+4x_3\\x_3'=4x_1-4x_2+3x_3\\x_1(0)=2,\ x_2(0)=1,\ x_3(0)=-1\end{cases}}$

I am having trouble solving this. I know one method involves finding the eigenvalues and eigenvectors but is there not a method without using linear algebra and eigenvalues?

Comment: The short answer is no, there isn't.

Comment: You've been on MSE for long enough now that you should really learn how to format the mathematics in your questions with MathJax. Here's an admittedly rather long but very helpful tutorial on how to do that: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Hint***

Solve this first then ...Substract 3) from 2)

$$x'_2-x'_3=-(x_2-x_3)$$
$$(x_2-x_3)'=-(x_2-x_3)$$

Substitute $z=x_2-x_3$

Then the equation becomes a simple first ODE easy to solve

$$z'=-z$$
$$\ln(z)=-t+K$$
$$z=Ke^{-t}$$
$$x_2(0)-x_3(0)=K \implies K=2 \implies x_2-x_3=2e^{-t}$$
First equation becomes ... 
$$
\begin{align}
1)x'_1&=3x_1-4x_2+4x_3\\
1)x'_1&=3x_1-4z\\
1)x'_1&=3x_1-8e^{-t}\\
\end{align}
$$
Which is easy to solve ..

---

***First equation ($x_1$)***

$$x'_1=3x_1-8e^{-t}$$
$$x'_1-3x_1=-8e^{-t}$$
$e^{-3t}$ as integrating factor
$$x'_1e^{-3t}-3x_1e^{-3t}=-8e^{-t}e^{-3t}$$
$$(x_1e^{-3t})'=-8e^{-4t}$$
Simply integrate now
$$x_1e^{-3t}=-8\int e^{-4t}dx =2e^{-4t}+C$$
$$x_1=2e^{-t}+Ce^{3t}$$
We need to evaluate the constant C  for $t=0$
$$x_1(0)=2+C  \implies C=0 \implies x_1=2e^{-t}$$
$$\boxed{x_1=2e^{-t}}$$

***Second Equation for $x_2$***
$$x'_2=4x_1-5x_2+4x_3$$
We know the value of $x_1$ and we have a relation between $x_2$ and $x_3$

Because $x_1=2e^{-t}$
$$x'_2=8e^{-t}-5x_2+4x_3$$
Because $x_2-x_3=2e^{-t} \implies x_3= x_2-2e^{-t}$
$$x'_2=8e^{-t}-5x_2+4(x_2-2e^{-t})$$
$$x'_2=-x_2$$
$$x_2=Re^{-t} $$
Evaluate the constant R for $t=0$
$$x_2(0)=1 \implies R=1$$
$$\boxed {x_2=e^{-t} }$$

***Third equation $x_3$***

You don't need to solve any differential equation since you have a relation between $x_2$ and $x_3$
$$x_3=x_2-2e^{-t} =e^{-t}-2^{-t}$$
Therefore
$$\boxed{x_3=-e^{-t}}$$
You have finished...

Comment: Can you explain why K = x2-x3?

Comment: it's equal to $K=x_2(0)-x_3(0)$ because $z(t)=Ke^{-t}$ and $t=0$ then  $K=z(0)=x_2(0)-x_3(0)$ @D.J.

Comment: I reached a problem when plugging into x'2, shouldn't the method here work for all the equations when plugging in?

Comment: Yes I solved x1 and x3, the problem I have is plugging back into the original equation to then solve the ordinary differential equation. For example, we plugged back in z which is (X2-X3) in the first step. I cannot find out how to do this for X'2.

Comment: I solved the system completely now @D.J.

Comment: Thank you very much, you cleared a lot of confusion! Much appreciated.

Comment: yw @D.J. hope it helped you